# JSP - exit executing the rest of the code

Tags: jsp, session

In the first line of my JSP page, I check for a session value is null. If null redirect back to login page.

When i tested it by loggingout and checked that page, it give a `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException` error.

So how to exit the code just after the sendRedirect line ?

Code:

```
<%
   if((session.getAttribute("user_type")==null) || (!session.getAttribute("user_type").equals("user")))
    {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");

        //prevent executing rest of code.
    }
%>

<html>
  <head>
    .......
```

To logout, I use only: `session.invalidate();`

Comment: Instead of response.sendRedirect...use <script>document.location=login.jsp</script>......This will directly redirect you to the login page without executing rest of the code...

Comment: I have found the problem. I have a jsp:include tag in that page. If user is not valid, the page to include using that tag was not provided. Now i have included a condition to check if session is null. If null, avoid that tag. This worked.

Comment: Great!! Add that answer here...so the ppl will atleast cum to kn what the prblm was....

Comment: @Shashank: you have 600 characters of space in a comment. Can you please be so kind to write words full out so that non-native English readers can also understand you? Right now you look like a childish teen who's conversating by SMS.

Comment: @BalusC: Sorry, I will take care of this from now onwards...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSP code is equivalent to:

```
if (someCondition) {
    redirect();
}
doPlentyOfOtherThings();
```

If you don't want to do plenty of other things, the code should be

```
if (someCondition) {
    redirect();
}
else {
    doPlentyOfOtherThings();
}
```

So it should look like that:

```
<%
    if((session.getAttribute("user_type")==null) || (!session.getAttribute("user_type").equals("user")))
    {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }
    else
    {
%>
<html>
    <head>
    .......
<%   } %>
```

Except that

- you shouldn't use scriptlets, but the JSP EL and the JSTL in JSP pages
- such a logic shouldn't be in a JSP, which should only have to generate markup. It should be in a servlet of action of your preferred MVC framework, which would redirect or dispatch to the JSP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 
Simply add the following line:

```
if ( true ) return;
```

Comment: Simply add ```return;```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more debugging, I found where this problem was causing.

I have a jsp:include tag. And in the main code, I only assigned the page to include if user is  valid(logged in). So, when user is loggedout, this tag was still trying to include it(I used a variable to pass the pagename).

What I have added:

```
<%
   if(session.getAttribute("user_type")!=null)
    {
%>
       <jsp:include.... />
<%
    }
%>
```

Now this jsp tag will not be considered during execution when user is not valid.